# Problems with emitting to all clients with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server1);
io.on('connection', function(io){
    socket_call_data = function(some,data){
        io.emit("new_peer_data", result);
    }

    io.on('event', function(data){
      //doing stuff
      socket_call_data(some,data);
    });
});
```

This is my current code and the problem is that `io.emit` (in the function socket_call_data) only seems to emit to the user who connected. So, after doing some reading, I used `io.broadcast.emit`. This worked great, however it does not include the user who connected - who I do also want to be sent the data. So, finally i came to find out about `io.sockets.emit` which supposedly sends it to all clients. But instead, i get the error:

```
Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: Cannot call method 'emit' of undefined
    at socket_call_data (/var/www/html/live_nodejs/handle.js:47:20)
```

So io.**sockets**.emit is not defined...

What am I getting wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're overwriting your `io` variable with a single socket when the user connects. Change the `io` arg on your `connection` event to `socket` instead:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server1);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket_call_data = function(some,data){
        io.emit("new_peer_data", result);
    }

    socket.on('event', function(data){
      //doing stuff
      socket_call_data(some,data);
    });
});
```

Then `io.emit()` should emit to all sockets.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you are passing `io` in the function

```
io.on('connection', function(io){
     //Your Code here
});
```

so, the Global `io` and the `io` that you are passing inside the function are becoming ambiguous. All you need to do is, change the `io` that you are passing inside the function to some other variable like `socket` or something.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
     //Your code here
     socket.emit("some event specific to this particular socket");
     io.sockets.emit("This event will be broadcasted to everyone connected");
});
```

This should help you out.